# Mac Terminal Display Column of the Cursor

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, osx-yosemite

How I can display the column position of either the cursor or the mouse pointer. Using the terminal on OSX 10.10

edited ---

[image]

I wanted to know which character was the R in over for example.

I managed to find how to display the number of rows and columns in the terminal, but that is not the requirement[image].

Answer (score 0):

An [answer over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343250/how-can-i-get-position-of-cursor-in-terminal) mentions the escape code `\033[6n`:

> For example, if you enter:
>
> `~$ echo -e "z033[6n"; cat > foo.txt`
>
> Press [ENTER] a couple times and then [CRTL]+[D]. Then try:
>
> `~$ cat -v foo.txt`
>
> `^[[47;1R`
>
> The n and m values are 47 and 1

*(thanks to [Paulo Scardine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444036/paulo-scardine))*

This may or may not do what you are looking for- do you have more context? If you are looking for the column number in a text file you are editing, many tools (eg `nano`, `vim` etc) have current position reporting; in `nano` for example you could press `Ctrl+c`, `vim` may display it by default depending on setup but if not you can use `:set ruler` to show the status bar.

If you are working with changing output and need to get the column number where a particular entry appears, you could use `awk` for thatmost likely.

Comment: You solution gives me the number of rows in the terminal window (47) and always gives me 1, as the column. I wanted the Mac terminal to show me the cursor placement in bash root, and not in VIM or Nano

Comment: @RyanHeitner Your updated question is a bit clearer; the comments on that question note the same issue (1 as column). From the author: "that's because the text is echoed to the terminal, which in turn might interpret the escape sequence and cut off things"

Comment: @RyanHeitner By bash root, do you mean in interactive mode? For context, what problem are you ultimately trying to solve by displaying the cursor position?

Comment: I wanted to sort something in my clipboard. > pbpaste | sort -K????? | pbcopy.   The??? Are the character position

Comment: Ah, that's a bit more clear thanks. I think for that you may have to do it from a script, as using the scape sequence from an interactive shell is returning the current column as 1, as you say.